# Export citations from Zotero

Tags: latex, bibtex

When I use Zotero to export Better BibTex files, it always exports the literature pdf file locations as below, which makes me feel very disturbed. But I can't find the option to turn it off in the settings.

What can I do to avoid exporting the file location?

```
@article{amin1993Jump,
  title = {Jump {{Diffusion Option Valuation}} in {{Discrete Time}}},
  author = {Amin, Kaushik I.},
  year = {1993},
  journal = {The Journal of Finance},
  volume = {48},
  number = {5},
  pages = {1833--1863},
  publisher = {{[American Finance Association, Wiley]}},
  issn = {0022-1082},
  doi = {10.2307/2329069},
  annotation = {ZSCC: 0000519},
  file = {C\:\\Alex\\Desktop\\Thesis\\Put\\Reference\\ref\\[1993][Amin]Jump Diffusion Option Valuation in Discrete Time.pdf}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add undesired fields in [export](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/installation/preferences/export/) options under

<kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Better BibTeX</kbd> → <kbd>Export</kbd> → <kbd>Fields</kbd> → <kbd>Fields to omit from export (comma-separated)</kbd>

[image: Better BibTeX export settings]

Comment: @Yoga No prob. Please feel free to [accept the answer if it helped with your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).